# C# - Refresh method periodically

Tags: c#, uwp, refresh

I want to refresh my UWP-UI periodically after like 5 minutes. I have a Method "Page_Loaded" where all information from the classes is sent to the UI-Elements.
So if i refresh this method, the UI would do too, right?

The Code is like this:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RootObject myWeather = await Openweathermap.GetWeather();
            string icon = String.Format("http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{0}@2x.png", myWeather.weather[0].icon);
            ResultImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(icon, UriKind.Absolute));

            TempTextBlock.Text = ((int)myWeather.main.temp).ToString() + "°";
            DescriptionTextBlock.Text = myWeather.weather[0].description;
            LocationTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name;

            var articlesList = NewsAPI.GetNews().Result.articles;
            lvNews.ItemsSource = articlesList;

            Welcometxt.Text = MainPage.WelcomeText();
        }
```

So, how do I refresh this method after 5 Minutes, so that it gets the new information and sends it to the UI?

Comment: Are you asking what mechanism to use to do the 5-minute refresh? I think in UWP it's called a `DispatcherTimer`. I wouldn't call the `Page_Loaded` event handler over and over though, as you'll want to use that for stuff that only happens once when the page is loaded, like set the initial data and start the timer perhaps. You should move this code (except the last line) into it's own method, then call the new method. Oh, and when I say "call a method", I mean the same thing that you mean when you say "refresh a method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how do I refresh this method after 5 Minutes, so that it gets the new information and sends it to the UI?

Repeatedly calling the `Page_Loaded` method is not a recommended practice, the recommended approach is to use `DispatcherTimer`, a timer within the UI thread.

We can extract the code inside `Page_Loaded` as a function.

```cs
private DispatcherTimer _timer;
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
}

private async Task GetData()
{
    RootObject myWeather = await Openweathermap.GetWeather();
    string icon = String.Format("http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{0}@2x.png", myWeather.weather[0].icon);
    ResultImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(icon, UriKind.Absolute));

    TempTextBlock.Text = ((int)myWeather.main.temp).ToString() + "°";
    DescriptionTextBlock.Text = myWeather.weather[0].description;
    LocationTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name;

    var articlesList = NewsAPI.GetNews().Result.articles;
    lvNews.ItemsSource = articlesList;

    Welcometxt.Text = MainPage.WelcomeText();
}

private async void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    await GetData();
}

private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await GetData();
    _timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

With `DispatcherTimer.Tick`, we can execute tasks regularly, and when we leave the page, we can stop the timer.